# Looking for a news dataset/database that updates daily news from around the world, besides GDELT

Tags: database, dataset, web-crawler, feed, gdelt

Looking for a news dataset/database that updates daily news from around the world, besides GDELT

I'm trying to crawl news from various countries using shared keywords.
Right now I'm using Gdelt, but when I input a keyword for searching, it returns maximum 75 articles, which is far less than what I was hoping for.
Also, for some reason, it mainly returns English news from different countries now, instead of news in local languages (I didn't specify the language).
Is there a better alternative than Gdelt?
Thanks.